# Unable to make button in table on 100% height of column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi i have problem with table. I am using bootstrap. In table there are columns (some of them are filled with data some of them not). Every column must be a button (empty columns too). I have issue to make Buttons in column on 100% height of td. 
One condition is that in td is div and in that div there is button. So structure looks like this:

```
<tr>
 <td>
   <div> //THIS DIV IS IMPORTANT i am using react-bootstrap framework and component Button is including that div inside 
     My text data empty or not
   </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I removed paddings, i make div and buttons on 100% height and width but button height is still not 100%. Where is the problem please?

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ev87hgua/3/)

I put here bad link before now it should be okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your fiddle and couple on notes:

1. Change `Bottom` element to `button`.
2. Since you are using bootstrap, you inherit style from them. The quickest way to override this is to use `!important`.

You can add: `table th, table td {padding: 0!important;}` and then `button {height: 100%}` would work as expected.

You can read more about bootstrap's tables on the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/).

Comment: Why i can't use only ```table td {padding: 0!important;}```

Answer (score 1):

What prevents the button from having 100% height is the padding in your table th and td.

```
.table td, .table th {
  padding: 0;
}
```